# No cucumber error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cucumber

I'm having trouble with Cucumber giving me unusable error messages, or perhaps it's a setting in Rails that I could alter? This is what my error message looks like:

```
 expected to find text "edit" in "Internal Server Error undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-05-14) at lvh.me:58126" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/products.rb:83:in `/^I visit that product$/'
      features/product_edit.feature:6:in `And I visit that product'
```

There's no file + line given where I could find the error. Does anyone have any idea how I can bring back meaningful error messages? This is the stack:

```
cucumber (1.3.3)
  builder (>= 2.1.2)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
  gherkin (~> 2.12.0)
  multi_json (~> 1.7.5)
  multi_test (~> 0.0.1)
cucumber-rails (1.3.1)
  capybara (>= 1.1.2)
  cucumber (>= 1.2.0)
  nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
  rails (~> 3.0)
poltergeist (1.3.0)
```

**Update: ** I just realized this only happens when using Poltergeist.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's giving you two helpful hints:

```
./features/step_definitions/products.rb:83
```

and

```
./features/product_edit.feature:6
```

The message is perfectly fine. Cucumber is telling you that the feature defined in `product_edit.feature` is not passing the validation since the server is returning an error 500 when reproducing the `And I visit the product` step.

Cucumber is server-agnostic, and would not "talk" to the underlying Rails world.

What you should do is look at the `steps_definitions/products.rb` file, line 83, and see what you are doing there. Then reproduce those steps in the browser and see what's going wrong. Probably it's related to a specific product show page.

Comment: You have to be sure to replicate the conditions placed in the `Given` and `When` descriptions.

Comment: I just realized this only happens when Poltergeist is used.